# How to scrape data from a React Modal Portal element that is not immediately available on the DOM?

Tags: python, reactjs, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape data from a web page. However, some of the data I need is in div elements with class "ReactModalPortal". The child elements of these divs are not available in the DOM until a button is clicked and the modal overlay appears. The text I need is in these child elements i.e. the text that appears in said modal overlay.

What is the quickest way of scraping this data in Python? I need to get this data off of thousands of pages and hence I want to avoid using a web driver/ browser automator (e.g. Selenium) to click the portal elements.

What the element looks like in the DOM prior to button click:

```
<div class="ReactModalPortal">
    <div data-reactid=".1"></div>
</div>
```

What the element looks like after button click, containing the text I want to scrape:

```
<div class="ReactModalPortal">
    <div data-reactid=".c" class="ReactModal__Overlay ReactModal__Overlay--after-open modalify-overlay">
        <div class="ReactModal__Content ReactModal__Content--after-open modalify modalify-container" tabindex="-1" data-reactid=".c.0">
            <div class="modalify-content" data-reactid=".c.0.0">
                <div class="object-modifier" data-reactid=".c.0.0.0">
                    <div class="object-modifier__group" data-reactid=".c.0.0.0.0">
                        <div class="modifier-group__description" data-reactid=".c.0.0.0.0.2">TEXT I WANT TO SCRAPE.</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: if you can share the link and objective, I will give it a try. Most of the time data is filled when the script executes in your browser.

Comment: @PankajJoshi Thank you. It's the item descriptions on this page https://deliveroo.co.uk/menu/london/whitechapel/yun-restaurant-east-central

Comment: which button do you click. Please give `https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests-html` a try it helps you scrape data which is dynamically brought on the page.

Comment: I was just about to suggest the same. [Requests-HTML](https://html.python-requests.org/) allows you to render a site before parsing the data. But I've never used it, nor do I know if it allows to "click" a button and whatnot. Still worth a look though.

Comment: So this library you have suggested looks very promising. When I print `request.text` I can see the text I want in there, along with a lot of other data in a string. However I can't figure out how to isolate this text. I tried using class accessors but they return nothing.

Answer (score 0):

As for the clicking, I'm not sure anyway around that without using a webdriver. But if you can grab the html that you need, then you should be able to use BeautifulSoup4 (bs4) and request python libraries. After installing your libraries, your python script should look something like this:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# URL of the website to scrape
url = 'http://www.yourweburlthatneedsscraping.com'

# Send a GET request to the URL and retrieve the HTML content
response = requests.get(url)
html = response.text

# Create a BeautifulSoup object
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

# Find the desired element and extract the text
target_element = soup.find('div', class_='modifier-group__description')
if target_element:
    text_to_scrape = target_element.text
    print(text_to_scrape)
else:
    print("Element not found.")
```